# Cannot locate recovery image

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, usb-mass-storage

I have Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo (GT-I9301I). I've installed ClockworkMod and made backup of all files in my device. I had no suitable external memory card for backup, so CWM saved it in phone's memory. I've planned to move that backup to my PC, but I cannot locate it neither looking through "My files" in my device, nor connecting device to PC using USB, although free memory was reduced by 5-6 GB after making backup. The only way I can actually locate the backup is in recovery mode selecting `- restore from/sdcard`. It says backup image is in `/sdcard/clockworkmod/backup'`, but I cannot find this folder on my device.

How do I find my backup files? If that's of any relevance, my phone is rooted. And I've also enabled "Show hidden files" option inside my device.

Comment: @beeshyams You' re correct. I was able to locate my backup using "Root Browser". Still, this does not help to transfer it to PC. Maybe I should just get external microSD card. Or maybe I'll look into those adb commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until Android version 4.4.2 the CWM backups are stored in `/data/media/clockworkmod/backup`  Reason for this as per the Reddit Post (see source below)

> In Android 4.2, backups are placed in a secure directory, inaccessible to other apps

Whether it is TWRP / CWM / Philz recovery, clearing "internal storage", does not wipe this folder, unless explicitly cleared, hence back ups remain safe

You should be able to view the backup by any root enabled file explorer

This backup can be transferred to

- External SD card by using a file explorer (to save space on internal SD)
- Laptop using  `adb pull /data/media/clockworkmod/backup`

**Source**

XDA Thread: [CWM Recovery restoring nandroid backup](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2619118)

Reddit Post: [Transferring CWM backups to my PC?](https://m.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/1e79a2/transferring_clockworkmod_backups_to_my_pc/)

`